# How do I unset an element's CSS attribute using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

If I set a CSS value on a specific element using:

```
$('#element').css('background-color', '#ccc');
```

I want to be able to unset that element-specific value and use the cascaded value, along the lines of:

```
$('#element').css('background-color', null);
```

But that syntax doesn't seem to work – is this possible using another syntax?

**Edit:** The value isn't inherited from the parent element – the original values comes from an element-level selector. Sorry for any confusion!

Answer (score 157, accepted):

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

> Setting the value of a style property to an empty string — e.g. `$('#mydiv').css('color', '')` — removes that property from an element if it has already been directly applied, whether in the HTML style attribute, through jQuery's `.css()` method, or through direct DOM manipulation of the `style` property. It does not, however, remove a style that has been applied with a CSS rule in a stylesheet or `<style>` element.

Comment: I came across this question when I had this problem. In my case I was setting the css attribute in a `style` attribute on the tag, so this method did not work. Applying the style with the `.css()` method instead of in the tag allowed me to remove it later.

Answer (score 18):

I think you can also do:

```
$('#element').css('background-color', '');
```

That's what I used to do a long time ago for the `display` property in plain-old-javascript to show/hide a field.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$('#element').css('background-color', 'inherit');
```

Comment: Inherit is unfortunately not the behavior I'm looking for: "the property takes the same computed value as the property for the element's parent" from http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html

Comment: More likely 'initial' than 'inherit'. 'Inherit' adapts from the parent, 'Initial' does what the word says.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, the syntax I thought was incorrect (with `null`) seems to be working -- my selector was just improperly formed, and thus yielding no elements. D'oh!

Comment: As of jquery 1.4.3 `css(..., null)` doesn't work and `css(..., '')` should be used instead -- http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7233

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth this appears not to work in IE 8 for 'filter,' I had to use this (in fadeIn callback):

`$(this).attr('style', $(this).attr('style').replace(/\bfilter:\s*;*/, ''));`

Obviously, I had need to remove an empty inline filter declaration so the CSS could take effect; there were other inline rules so I couldn't just remove the style attribute.

Answer (score -3):

If it can help, I add a problem with double quote :

```
$('#element').css("border-color", "");
```

does not work while

```
$('#element').css('border-color', '');
```

works