# How can I remove a style added with .css() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm changing **CSS** with **jQuery** and I wish to remove the styling I'm adding based on the input value:

```
if(color != '000000') $("body").css("background-color", color); else // remove style ?
```

> How can I do this?
>   Note that the line above runs whenever a color is selected using a color picker (ie. when the mouse moves over a color wheel).

2nd note: I can't do this with `css("background-color", "none")` because it will remove the default styling from the **CSS** files.
I just want to remove the `background-color` inline style added by **jQuery**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I unset an element's CSS attribute using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490910/how-do-i-unset-an-elements-css-attribute-using-jquery)

Comment: better try addClass / removeClass based on your fcuntionality. This wont affect other styling.

Comment: 2 ways to remove style in jquery with  demo https://codepedia.info/jquery-remove-inline-style

Answer (score 1434, accepted):

Changing the property to an empty string appears to do the job:

```
$.css("background-color", "");
```

Comment: I have to side with @baacke here. Our customer still has an official minimum requirement of IE6(!!). Problem is, their customers are all over the world, including less developed countries. The "customer's customers" may be using *very* old computers to do business with our customer. So old browser must be at least minimally supported or they risk losing business...

Comment: You guys don't get to set the requirements of any solution you develop for a client. If that client wants or needs support for an older browser, it;s your job to provide it, period. You guys talking about "who cares" give true engineers a bad name.

Answer (score 585):

[The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4036868/187606) works but leaves an empty `style` attribute on the DOM in my tests. No big deal, but this removes it all:

```
removeAttr( 'style' );
```

This assumes you want to remove all dynamic styling and return back to the stylesheet styling.

Comment: what about from react appliccation?

Answer (score 183):

There are several ways to remove a CSS property using jQuery:

**1. Setting the CSS property to its default (initial) value**

```
.css("background-color", "transparent")
```

See the [initial value for the CSS property at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/background-color).
Here the default value is `transparent`. You can also use [`inherit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit) for several CSS properties to inherite the attribute from its parent. In CSS3/CSS4, you may also use [`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial), [`revert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert) or [`unset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset) but these keywords may have limited browser support.

**2. Removing the CSS property**

An empty string removes the CSS property, i.e.

```
.css("background-color","")
```

But beware, as specified in [jQuery .css() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2), this removes the property but it has compatibilty issues with IE8 for certain CSS shorthand properties, including **background**.

> Setting the value of a style property to an empty string — e.g.
>   $('#mydiv').css('color', '') — removes that property from an element
>   if it has already been directly applied, whether in the HTML style
>   attribute, through jQuery's .css() method, or through direct DOM
>   manipulation of the style property. It does not, however, remove a
>   style that has been applied with a CSS rule in a stylesheet or 
>   element. Warning: **one notable exception is that, for IE 8 and below,
>   removing a shorthand property such as border or background will
>   remove that style entirely from the element, regardless of what is set
>   in a stylesheet or  element**.

**3. Removing the whole style of the element**

```
.removeAttr("style")
```

Answer (score 56):

I got the way to remove a style attribute with pure JavaScript just to let you know the way of pure JavaScript

```
var bodyStyle = document.body.style;
if (bodyStyle.removeAttribute)
    bodyStyle.removeAttribute('background-color');
else        
    bodyStyle.removeProperty('background-color');
```

Comment: because jquery isn't every thing , because she or perhaps i should say every one of us as developers should know what compatibility means and how to do such a stuff with core languages as JavaScript, 
perhaps this is my theory i created already my own framework from my knowledge of core JavaScript  i refuses to use others things i have my own concept and my way of thinking :) and by the way thanks for your ( - ) i just needed to be value add :) and also by the way the guy isnt a guy she is a she named Alex

Answer (score 26):

This will remove complete tag :

```
  $("body").removeAttr("style");
```

Answer (score 19):

either of these jQuery functions should work:

```
$("#element").removeAttr("style");
$("#element").removeAttr("background-color")
```

Comment: To remove only one css property:
`var cssObject = $('selector').prop('style');
cssObject.removeProperty('background-color');`

Answer (score 11):

Just using:

```
$('.tag-class').removeAttr('style');
```

or

```
$('#tag-id').removeAttr('style');
```

Answer (score 10):

2018

there is native API for that

```
element.style.removeProperty(propery)
```

Answer (score 7):

How about something like:

```
var myCss = $(element).attr('css');
myCss = myCss.replace('background-color: '+$(element).css('background-color')+';', '');
if(myCss == '') {
  $(element).removeAttr('css');
} else {
  $(element).attr('css', myCss);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you use CSS style, you can use:

```
$("#element").css("background-color","none");
```

and then replace with:

```
$("#element").css("background-color", color);
```

If you don't use CSS style and you have attribute in HTML element, you can use:

```
$("#element").attr("style.background-color",color);
```

Answer (score 7):

Use my Plugin :

```
$.fn.removeCss=function(all){
        if(all===true){
            $(this).removeAttr('class');
        }
        return $(this).removeAttr('style')
    }
```

For your case ,Use it as following :

```
$(<mySelector>).removeCss();
```

or

```
$(<mySelector>).removeCss(false);
```

if you want to remove also CSS defined in its classes :

```
$(<mySelector>).removeCss(true);
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
$('#divID').css({"background":"none"});// remove existing

$('#divID').css({"background":"#bada55"});// add new color here.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This one also work!!

```
$elem.attr('style','');
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not make the style you wish to remove a CSS class? Now you can use: `.removeClass()`. 
This also opens up the possibility of using: `.toggleClass()`

(remove the class if it's present, and add it if it's not.)

Adding / removing a class is also less confusing to change / troubleshoot when dealing with layout issues (as opposed to trying to figure out why a particular style disappeared.)

Answer (score 2):

```
let el = document.querySelector(element)
let styles = el.getAttribute('style')

el.setAttribute('style', styles.replace('width: 100%', ''))
```

Answer (score 2):

you remove style using

`removeAttr( 'style' );`

Answer (score 1):

Simple is cheap in web development. I recommend using empty string when removing a particular style

```
$(element).style.attr = '  ';
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more complex than some other solutions, but may offer more flexibility in scenarios:

1) Make a class definition to isolate (encapsulate) the styling you want to apply/remove selectively. It can be empty (and for this case, probably should be):

```
.myColor {}
```

2) use this code, based on http://jsfiddle.net/kdp5V/167/ from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115325/change-css-rule-in-class-using-jquery/7014965#7014965)  by [gilly3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/361684/gilly3):

```
function changeCSSRule(styleSelector,property,value) {
    for (var ssIdx = 0; ssIdx < document.styleSheets.length; ssIdx++) {
        var ss = document.styleSheets[ssIdx];
        var rules = ss.cssRules || ss.rules;
        if(rules){
            for (var ruleIdx = 0; ruleIdx < rules.length; ruleIdx++) {
                var rule = rules[ruleIdx];
                if (rule.selectorText == styleSelector) {
                    if(typeof value == 'undefined' || !value){
                        rule.style.removeProperty(property);
                    } else {
                        rule.style.setProperty(property,value);
                    }
                    return; // stops at FIRST occurrence of this styleSelector
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example: http://jsfiddle.net/qvkwhtow/

Caveats:

- Not extensively tested.
- Can't include **!important** or other directives in the new value. Any such existing directives will be lost through this manipulation.
- Only changes first found occurrence of a styleSelector. Doesn't add or remove entire styles, but this could be done with something more elaborate.
- Any invalid/unusable values will be ignored or throw error.
- In Chrome (at least), non-local (as in cross-site) CSS rules are not exposed through document.styleSheets object, so this won't work on them. One would have to add a local overrides and manipulate that, keeping in mind the "first found" behavior of this code.
- document.styleSheets is not particularly friendly to manipulation in general, don't expect this to work for aggressive use.

Isolating the styling this way is what CSS is all about, even if manipulating it isn't. Manipulating CSS rules is NOT what jQuery is all about, jQuery manipulates DOM elements, and uses CSS selectors to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$(".ClassName").css('color','');
Or 
$("#Idname").css('color','');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 $("#eslimi").removeAttr("style").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
document.body.style=''
```

```js
$("body").css("background-color", 'red');

function clean() {
  document.body.style=''
}
```

```css
body { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="clean()">Remove style</button>
```