# Change CSS rule in class using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a class in CSS

```
.Foo
{
  width:20px;
}
```

Using Jquery I would like to do something similar to this on an event:

```
$(".Foo").css("width", "40px");
```

This doesn't work. Is this the wrong approach? Should I use addClass() and removeClass()?

EDIT: I figured out my problem. This command does in fact work. In my particular application I hadn't created the elements using the class before I used the command, so when they were created nothing was changed.

Basically this command doesn't change the CSS style rule, just the elements using the class.

Comment: can you look at your console and see if your are getting any errors? that command should work

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`jQuery.css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) will find all *existing* elements on the page that have the `Foo` class, and then set their *inline* style `width` to `40px`.

In other words, this doesn't create or change a css rule -- if you dynamically add an element with the `Foo` class, it would still have a width of `20px`, because its inline style hasn't been set to override the default CSS rule.

Instead, you should use [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) and control the styles in your static CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation; a code example would've been nice.

Comment: What if the css rule is referenced by id, e.g. `#some-id`?

Answer (score 69):

You *can* change a CSS style rule.  You need to look at:

`document.styleSheets` collection
`styleSheet.cssRules` property (or `styleSheet.rules` for IE7 and IE8)
`rule.selectorText` property
`rule.style` property

For example:

```
var ss = document.styleSheets[0];
var rules = ss.cssRules || ss.rules;
var fooRule = null;
for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++)
{
    var rule = rules[i];
    if (/(^|,) *\.Foo *(,|$)/.test(rule.selectorText))
    {
        fooRule = rule;
        break;
    }
}
fooRule.style.width = "40px";
```

Working demo: [jsfiddle.net/kdp5V](http://jsfiddle.net/kdp5V/)

Comment: I found this answer very helpful - ultimately, I ended up using something similar to  `for (i in document.styleSheets[0].rules) 
  if (document.styleSheets[0].rules[i].selectorText == ".setThisRule") 
 document.styleSheets[0].rules[i].style.maxWidth = "100px";`

Comment: @krivar - What version?  Works for me in the current release (Version 32.0.1700.72 m).  What errors do you see in the JavaScript console?

Comment: @gilly3
 - Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
 - Chromium: Version 31.0.1650.63 (238485)
 - OS: Manjaro Linux

Comment: @krivar - Did you change the jsFiddle?  Or, if you click [the link to my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kdp5V/), open the JavaScript console, then click "Turn the border blue", *without changing anything*, you see the error?

Comment: yes, i still get the error. I have not changed anything. My chromium is updated to Version 32.0.1700.77 (244343). [Link to screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/7fQUoZA.png)

Comment: @krivar - Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/kdp5V/167/.  This is a bit baffling to me.  My guess is that the stylesheet containing the rule is not at index 2 in your OS.  If this updated jsFiddle works for you, that will confirm it.  And, if it fails, it should fail silently (if that's better).

Comment: yep, @gilly3, this one works good. Border turns blue (also turns double-stroke into single-stroke)

Comment: Apparently this happens on Chrome: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=49001

Answer (score 19):

you could add the styling manually to the header with jquery:

```
  $('head').append('<style id="addedCSS" type="text/css">.Foo {width:40px;}</style>');
```

then change it on an event like e.g. so:

```
  $(window).resize(function(){
     $('#addedCSS').text('.Foo {width:80px;}');
  });
```

Comment: Ah, nice one. Simple and elegant, exactly what I was looking for--though now that I re-read the question above, maybe not the best answer here.

Comment: P.S. I think you mean `$('head')` (not 'header')! :)

Comment: This is a brilliant technique, to script the style-sheet rule: so if no functioning JavaScript or jQuery, then neither part will execute.

Comment: Nice answer for adding and changing dynamic css rule

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should use addClass and removeClass to change the styling. In your css, define a couple of different classes and switch between them.

Answer (score 2):

You should be selecting an element with jQuery. You're aware that you aren't selecting the CSS class itself, correct?

Once you have an element with class="Foo", you can select it as you have, and either set css properties manually like you're trying to do, or you can use add class like so:

```
$(".Foo").addClass('Foo');
```

Granted of course, since you're selecting the same class that you're adding, it doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I got thsi example in CSS api help in JQuery API.

this worked for me : http://jsfiddle.net/LHwL2/

for complete help read the css api at http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

Try using multiple styles

```
.FooSmall
{
  width:20px;
}
.FooBig
{
  width:40px;
}

$('#theTarget').removeClass('FooSmall').addClass('FooBig');
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you.

```
$(".Foo").css("width", "40px");
```