# How i can make a dynamic css class without use of id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How i can make a dynamic css class without use of id.

```
$( "#mydiv" ).css( "width", $("#widthtextbox").val() );

$( "#mydiv" ).css( "height", $("#heighttextbox").val() );
```

i want to use several css class for the work.

Comment: what do you mean by 'dynamic css class' ? Did you see this : http://api.jquery.com/addClass/ ?

Comment: i have a problem when i use .css() ,this method change my classوWhereas i want reuse this class for another div.and i think this problem is for id.

Comment: How does it change ? if you have a class `my_class` defined in your style sheet, you can add (`addClass`) it  to  or remove(`removeClass`) it from any element with jQuery.

Comment: I hope you are looking for solution like this (2nd answer). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115325/change-css-rule-in-class-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use class name for the same,

```
$(".className").css("","");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use class selector

```
$(".yourclass")
```

this should solve it