# change class css using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a class which uses a media query:

css:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 58.75em)
.top-bar-section ul li {
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  transform: skewX(15deg);
}
```

Now if the value of `City()` is London I want to change that css above to say:

```
 @media only screen and (min-width: 58.75em)
    .top-bar-section ul li {
      border-left: 1px solid #fff;
      transform: skewX(-15deg);
    }
```

My javascript is:

```
if (City() == "London"){
//change the css class from the first example to the 2nd?
}
```

Any help on how I can do this with jQuery to change a classes css?
Thanks,
Josh

Comment: the media query condition is for both the same !

Comment: Make second class and use removeClass and addClass

Comment: @legends transform property value is differs

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you elaborate what you've tried so far please? jQuery offers an `addClass()` method as well as one for removing - have you tried these?

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115325/change-css-rule-in-class-using-jquery) if helpful to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For specifying the css you can use the `.css()`-function of jQuery:

```
$('.top-bar-section ul li').css({
  '-webkit-transform' : 'skewX(-15deg)',
  '-moz-transform'    : 'skewX(-15deg)',
  '-ms-transform'     : 'skewX(-15deg)',
  '-o-transform'      : 'skewX(-15deg)',
  'transform'         : 'skewX(-15deg)'
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bxqg2m16/)

Or you can specify a second class, e.g.:

```
.top-bar-section ul li.london {
    transform: skewX(-15deg);
}
```

and call

```
$('.top-bar-section ul li').addClass('london');
```

inside your if-condition. For removing the class you can use `.removeClass()`

**Reference**

[.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

[.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

[.removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do with the help of jQuery, by adding jQuery `newClass` if specified condition is true, and use jQuery `removeClass` vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

you can use addClass and removeClass methods to make it.

Answer (score 0):

you can change classes using jQuery with the class attributes, here's the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/)