# How to remove style property

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery - remove style added with .css() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036857/jquery-remove-style-added-with-css-function)

I want to remove the style property from the div , i cannot use the removeAttribute and removeProperty as removeAttribute removes whole style and remove Property doesnot works in ie.
Is there any other way to do it.

```
<div style="visiblity:hidden;margin-right:10px;margin-left:10px">
```

I want to remove only visibility style property.

Comment: Have you tried parsing and editing the value of the `style` property using JavaScript?

Comment: @RichardEv IMHO that would be a sledge hammer to crack a nut...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [.css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) as such

```
$(elementSelect).css('marginRight', null);
```

or

```
$(elementSelect).css('marginRight', '0px').css('visibility', 'visible');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css function of jQuery

```
$('div').css({'visibility':'visible'});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one :

```
$('div').css('visibility', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
<div id="testDiv" style="visiblity:hidden;margin-right:10px;margin-left:10px">Here</div>

$('#testDiv').attr('style', function(i, style) {
    return style.replace(/visiblity[^;]+;?/g, '');
});
```

Example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cThKf/5/)

Comment: There's no need to do that when you can use the jquery .css function

Answer (score -3):

Add runat="server" and then you could override the Visibility parameter from the code-behind

Comment: Maybe OP just a web designer and do not use server at all.

Comment: let alone an ASP.net server...