# jquery: add a style attribute to existing style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Add a style attribute to existing style properties

I have a div element:

```
<div id="permissions" style="clear: both; float: left;">
```

I want to set border on onsubmit event:

```
<div id="permissions" style="clear: both; float: left; border: 1px #F00 solid; ">
```

Is there a way to do this: 
Append new style attribute (border) to existing styles (with out reading existing styles)?

Comment: Tried anything yet? Seems very basic. http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: I am a jquery newbie.
I have tried $('#persmissions').attr('style', '...') but dint work. I thought $('#permissions').css() will do the same. I Google'd but dint find examples for my case and not here either so I've asked this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As an alternative to manipulating the style directly you could have a css class:

```
.submitted
{
    border: 1px #F00 solid;
}
```

Then using jQuery:

```
$('#permissions').addClass('submitted');
```

Then to remove:

```
$('#permissions').removeClass('submitted');
```

Then if you want to reuse the same approach elsewhere, you can just use the `submitted` class. Also if you want to extend the class (e.g. change the color) you can just edit the `submitted` class.

Comment: This is not what the OP asked for and should not be the accepted solution, see the answer by "lolcaks" below.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the css() method of jquery:

```
$('#permissions').css('border','1px #000 dashed');
```

Comment: It would be great if you could show us how to remove the added style, like acarlon did in its solution!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer to "jquery: add a style attribute to existing style" because that is exactly what this is doing, not adding classes. I needed the exact style added to my style attribute, but using $('#permissions').attr('style',"border: 1px #000 dashed"); replaced my existing styles, where $('#<id>').css('<style>','<value>'); appended to my existing styles as the OP requested. Thanks!

Comment: @aldemarcalazans, the OP did not ask for that, but you can get that answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036857/how-can-i-remove-a-style-added-with-css-function

Answer (score 2):

You can add style to existing style or override existing style like this.

```
var style =$('#permissions').attr('style'); //it will return string
//on submit update style as
style += ';border: 1px #F00 solid;';
$('#permissions').attr('style',style);
```

It will not affect your existing style and will add your new style to existing one even if you'll have to override any other property as well.

Answer (score 1):

Sure:

```
$('#permissions').css({
  borderWidth: 1,
  borderColor: '#fff',
  borderStyle: 'solid'
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e5ZdJ/).

Comment: It would be great if you could show us how to remove the added style, like acarlon did in its solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
  $('#permissions').css("border","1px #F00 solid");
});
```

Comment: It would be great if you could show us how to remove the added style, like acarlon did in its solution!

Comment: @aldemarcalazans if you want to remove a style, then you can reset it using `.css()` again, with a new appropriate value. `unset`, `none`, `auto` or 0