# Changing color back to default in CSS and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In my Code i have 10 different list items i want to show the currently clicked item in Red colour as if the current item changed the colour should revert back to Default colour.Is there any way to do it ??

```
$(this).css("color","red");
```

I used this inside my "click" event to change the current element's colour.

Comment: why not use `.addClass('red')` where `.red{color:red}` ?

Comment: [Repeated question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036857/jquery-remove-style-added-with-css-function).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reset all other `li` elements before applying `css`

```js
$('li').on('click', function() {
  $('li').css('color', '');//WIll remove `color` css from all `li` elements
  $(this).css('color', 'red');//Will apply `red` to current element
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

**Note:** As suggested by others, playing with `class` is better habit

```js
$('li').on('click', function() {
  $('li.red').removeClass('red');//Will remove `red` class from `li Element` having class as `red`
  $(this).addClass('red');//Add class to clicked element
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).css("color","red");
```

Before this set all elements color to default for Example 
if list of items has class name myclass
you can set

```
 $(".myclass").css("color","red");
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do it like this:

```
$(this).css("color", "");
```

...but rather than using direct styling, in general I'd suggest using a *class* and adding it (`addClass`) when you want those styles applied, and removing it (`removeClass`) when you want them removed. `toggleClass` is also really handy.

Example of both:

```js
var direct = false;
var usingClass = false;
$("#direct").on("click", function() {
  direct = !direct;
  if (direct) {
    $(this).css("color", "red");
  } else {
    $(this).css("color", "");
  }
  return false;
});
$("#using-class").on("click", function() {
  usingClass = !usingClass;
  $(this).toggleClass("the-class", usingClass);
  return false;
});
```

```css
.the-class {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Click to toggle.</p>
<p id="direct">Direct</p>
<p id="using-class">Using class</p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use Jquery toggleClass

```
<a class="default" onclick="changeColor(this)">default</div>


function changeColor(cntrl)
{
$(cntrl).toggleClass ("red");
}

.default
{

}
.red
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> i want to show the currently clicked item in Red colour as if the
>   current item changed the colour should revert back to Default colour

You can use `<a>` element, `:target`, adjacent sibling `+` selectors, `css` `animation`. f requirement is to set `color` until a sibling `li` element is clicked, remove `animation`, set `color` at selector

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  cursor: default;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 18px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 18px;
}
a + div {
  font-size: 18px;
}
:target + div {
  animation: togglecolor 5s linear 0s forwards;
}
@keyframes togglecolor {
  from {
    color: red;
  }
  to {
    color: initial;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a id="1" href="#1"></a>
    <div>link 1</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="2" href="#2"></a>
    <div>link 2</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="3" href="#3"></a>
    <div>link 3</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="4" href="#4"></a>
    <div>link 4</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="5" href="#5"></a>
    <div>link 5</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="6" href="#6"></a>
    <div>link 6</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="7" href="#7"></a>
    <div>link 7</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="8" href="#8"></a>
    <div>link 8</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="9" href="#9"></a>
    <div>link 9</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="10" href="#10"></a>
    <div>link 10</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```