# how to remove CSS property from a HTML tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I am unable to remove CSS property for a HTML tag.

I am trying to remove position style property from css. Actually it's coming from parent, I am able to override it with my css file but i want to remove postion property completely as per my requirement.

Below code, I tried, But it didn't work for me

```
$("p").removeProp("position");
```

Example for my code (Note: I don't have any className for P tag)

```js
$("p").removeProp("position");
```

```css
p {
  position: static;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Hello Stack Overflow
</p>
```

Comment: Try `$("p").css({"position": "initial"});`

Comment: `$("p").css("position", "unset");` may also work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove a style added with .css() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036857/how-can-i-remove-a-style-added-with-css-function)

Comment: any value to the position is is not working for me, In my case i need to remove position property completely.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove them by:

```
$("p").css("position",'');
```

As mentioned in the jquery documentation:

> Setting the value of a style property to an empty string — e.g.
>   `$(selector).css('color', ' ')` — removes that property from an element
>   if it has already been directly applied.

To remove the whole in-line style of an element use:

```
$(selector).removeAttr('style');
```

Your actual problem seems that you have added `css` property on `p` tag.
You should implement either use of `class` or use`!important` to replace. The best way is to use `class`

```css
.p-static {
  position: static;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: red;
}
.p-normal {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="p-static">
  Hello Stack Overflow, this is static paragrap.
</p>
<p class="p-normal">
  Hello Stack Overflow, this is normal paragraph.
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Sushil, But this line of code is not working for me. I tried the code in coponentDidMount() life cycle method. It's not at all replacing or removing

Comment: you shouldn't add `p {
  position: static;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: red;
}`. what you have to do is use some class or use inline.

Answer (score 0):

With help of jQuery you can achieve this easily

```
$("p").css({ 'postion': '' });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response balaji, But it's not working for me. I tried using this code in componentDIdMount() lifecycle method

Comment: Are you trying to use jQuery inside react project.