# Change CSS entry using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have this html.

```
<div class="menu">File</div>
<div class="menu">Edit</div>
<div class="menu">Help</div>
```

And I have this CSS.

```
.menu { 
    float:left; 
    width:150px; 
    position: relative;
}
```

For some reason, I need to disable the float:left and position:relative, and return it to "unset" state, **if** I click on a special button. But this code doesn't work.

```
function doThat() {
    $('.menu').css ( { "float":"", "position":"" } );
}
```

How can I do this? The problem is this is not an inline CSS. Thanks.

---

**EDIT:** so according to the solution works for me from @alexfreiria, I append the answer here.

```
function doThat() {
    $('.menu').css ( { "float":"inherit", "position":"inherit" } );
}
```

And this works on IE. Thank you all!

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490910/how-do-i-unset-an-elements-css-attribute-using-jquery for why this doesnt work

Comment: @DelightedD0D I know. That's why I said "The problem is this is not an inline CSS." So there's no solution to make this work?

Comment: My bad I missed that satement : )

Comment: @DelightedD0D not to worry. :) all is good!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
function doThat() {
    $('.menu').css ( { "float":"", "position":"" } );
}
```

To:

```
function doThat() {
    $('.menu').css ( { "float":"initial", "position":"initial" } );
}
```

More on the [`inherit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit), [`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) and [`unset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset) property values.

Comment: Wait, is that means you asked me to use either the inherit or initial, or use the literal "inherit|initial" ?

Comment: It's better to specify `none` and `static` instead of using `initial` which is not supported in IE

Comment: @Mr.Alien thank you for the clarification! But at least inherit works in my case, and it's in IE. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
$('.menu').css ({
   'float': 'none', //initial state is none
   'position': 'static' //initial state is static
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand your explanation. But I think the answer from @alexfreiria is more general, because I don't have to remember about what is the initial state, and better yet, I also don't have to remember the inherited state from its parent. But thank you anyway!